# Angular 17.2.4 ESBuild ng serve does not recompile after error

Tags: angular, vite, esbuild, serve, ng

With Angular version 17.2.4 and using ESBuild when a compile error is corrected and the app is launched with **ng serve**, the old version is launched and a Vite error popup is displayed showing the error of the old version. It seems that Vite does not rebuild the app.

After closing the error popup running ng serve again launches the debug session without error.

How can I fix this?

I followed the instructions to enable ESBuild
I tried prerender but it did not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.